# Nuget upgrade Azure webjobs SDK 2.3 to 3.0 when using serviceBus

Tags: azure, nuget, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

Webjobs version 3 has been out since around September so I want to upgrade from 2.3.0 to the latest version, currently 3.0.4.

The Microsoft.Azure.Webjobs.servicebus package is, however, blocking me from doing so. I tried looking at [webjobs sdk samples](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-samples) but they had the exact same issue with the servicebus package blocking the upgrade.

**Questions**

1. What is the correct way to upgrade the webjobs nuget package?
2. Am I mistaken that version 3 is ready for production yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the time I'm writing this, the newest release version of Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus is 2.3.0. [Looking at the package on nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus/2.3.0) and expanding the dependencies, I see this:

```
Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.EventProcessorHost (>= 2.2.10)
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs (= 2.3.0)
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions (>= 1.1.1) Newtonsoft.Json
(>= 9.0.1) WindowsAzure.ServiceBus (>= 3.4.5)
```

Notice how the version number for the Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs dependency uses `=` and not `>=` like the other dependencies. Therefore, NuGet is being instructed to not allow different versions of the package.

There are some 3.0.0 beta packages you could try, which interestingly use `>=` for the WebJobs dependency, so you can use the latest "release" version of WebJobs package while using the ServiceBus beta package. Or, if you can [migrate from packages.config to PackageReference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference), NuGet may allow you to use "incompatible" versions of packages with a warning, but if the package author is telling you that their package only works with a specific version of a dependency, there's an increased risk that you'll get runtime failures if you use a different version.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the package `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus` [on nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus),  it doesn't seem to be  maintained:

- The last release was on 29 Nov 2018 - over a year ago.
- The last beta was on 30 Aug 2018, also over a year ago. Several betas, with no release following them.

This looks abandoned. Has the package been renamed? Or the functionality folded into a different package? Why is there no upgrade path guidance here?

The disparity between the dependencies of this package and others in use are starting to cause issues for us.